# cakephp validate number as well floating number, should not allow alphanumeric

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

how to validate amount in cakephp,

validation rule: should not accept empty space, should not alpha numeric, should not accept special character except dot(.),

example:

should accept below values

12
12.0
12.00
133

should not accept below values

123_33/#$#%#$%#
a1a1455
   asd
fadsfads

actual thing is, this field for payment gateway, so before sending amount to payment gateway, we should make sure, we are sending decimal or full integer.

information: working in cakephp framkework

Comment: Did you check online API docs or source code for a numeric or currency class? Chances are they have it built in (ie inflector class).

Comment: Numeric is what you want

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do the following

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::money

```
//2.0
    var $validate = array(
        'salary' => array(
            'rule' => array('money', 'left'),
            'message' => 'Please supply a valid monetary amount.'
        )
    );
```

If you are using 1.3 try

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Data-Validation.html#money

If can also try decimal http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Data-Validation.html#decimal

```
//2.0
    public $validate = array(
        'price' => array(
            'rule' => array('decimal', 2)
        )
    );
```

Also consider Numeric http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::numeric

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var $validate = array(
    'amount' => array(
    'rule' => array('decimal', 2)
    )
    );
```

Hope it helps